# php 8.1 disable deprecated warnings on nginx on ubuntu server 2020.04

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu server 20.04. my php version is php8.1.20, there installed nginx and mysql.
There is Deprecated warning with some php functions(strlen, strtolower). How can I hide it. error reporting is not working.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by `error reporting is not working`? Where are you seeing these warnings? Can you edit you question and add more details and the exact text of the warnings your are getting?